# Get "handles" of characteristics using FlutterBlue?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

Repeat of https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/868

On Windows, I have some code that looks like:

```
  wclGattClient.ReadCharacteristicValue(errorchar, wclGattOperationFlag.goNone, out var Value);
  foreach (uint16 handle in Value)
  {
     foreach(chars in service)
       if(chars.handle == handle)
       {
        wclGattClient.ReadCharacteristicValue(errorchar, wclGattOperationFlag.goNone, out var Val2);
         print("UUID %s is flagged : %s", chars.uuid, Val2.toString());
       } 
  }
```

ie, the device is returning a list of Handles that are in an alert status (so I can read them and present the condition to the user), and I need to match that up with the Handle of the char in the discoverServices so I know which ones to get the data from...

How do I do this with flutter_blue?

Comment: Your link does not work because it includes a trailing semi-colon

Answer (score 0):

The flutter_blue [documentation](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue) on Github includes a part about [reading and writing characteristics](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue#read-and-write-characteristics):

```dart
// Reads all characteristics
var characteristics = service.characteristics;
for(BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
    List<int> value = await c.read();
    print(value);
}

// Writes to a characteristic
await c.write([0x12, 0x34])
```

In this example `BluetoothCharacteristic c`would be your handle you can use to read and write values to.

Comment: Ack... A level deeper.
All BLE traffic to a device is made with a 16 bit number for the characteristic/service/attribute/etc (a Handle) in wcl parlance).  The first thing you should do is discoverServices to get the services (with their full UUIDs) and the mapping to the Handles.

The FlutterBlue libraray has its own objects -- `BluetoothCharacteristic` s that you use to interact with the device, but... in my case I need to be find the BLE handle in the GATT table so I can go back and say "UUID 08231-3312-xxx-3323 is in error; its current value is 83.2"